# Remove the extra symbol "<>" in WordPress registration email

Tags: wordpress

When you enable the function that allows anyone to register on your WordPress website, WordPress sends a link which looks like this:

```
<https://your-domain.com/wp-login.php? 
action=rp&key=DFmJxTfZvqYQKJOAhBtA&login=Alice%20Cooper>
```

Unfortunately, some popular email providers, such as iCloud can't read <> tag properly. As a result, a visitor who is about to register on your website receives an error "Your password reset link appears to be invalid. Please request a new link below."

How could I force WordPress to remove this tag <...> in order to send the clear link?

P.s.: I know about the so-called "caching issues." In my case, I hope anyone might advice some add_action or another solution.

Comment: Try to [filter wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail/)

Comment: In the case of custom registration I might do everything manually, wp_generate_password, wp_mail, etc... But my goal is to use the default WordPress registration form and its functionality... and I can't realize why WordPress can't send this links without this <...> tag by default?

Comment: You don't need. Just update the `message` attribute in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the wp_mail function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail','remove_tags' );
function remove_tags( $args ){
    $args['message'] = str_replace( '<', '', $args['message'] );
    $args['message'] = str_replace( '>', '', $args['message'] );
    return $args;    
}
```

More information here: [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail/).

Comment: Thank you, IvnH! Your solution works great! At first I didn't realize that I can apply the filter to wp_mail!